# Reading another packages symbol table in Perl

Tags: perl, typeglob

I am trying to read a global symbol from another package. I have the package name as a string.
I am using `qualify_to_ref` from `Symbol` module

```
    my $ref  = qualify_to_ref ( 'myarray', 'Mypackage' ) ;
    my @array =  @$ref ;
```

gives me `Not an ARRAY reference at ......`  I presume I am getting the format of the dereference wrong.

Here is a complete example program.

```
    use strict;
    use Symbol ;

    package Mypackage ;
    our @myarray = qw/a b/ ;

    package main ;

    my $ref  = qualify_to_ref ( 'myarray', 'Mypackage' ) ;
    my @array =  @$ref ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `qualify_to_ref` function returns a typeglob reference, which you can de-reference like this:

```
my @array =  @{*$ref};
```

The typeglob dereferencing syntax is documented [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References).

Answer (score 5):

You can also do this without using an external module, as discussed in [perldoc perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Symbol-Tables) under "Symbol Tables":

```
package Mypackage;
use strict;
use warnings;
our @myarray = qw/a b/;

package main;

our @array;
*array = \@Mypackage::myarray;
print "array from Mypackage is @array\n";
```

However, whether this is a good idea depends on the context of your program. Generally it would be a better idea to use an accessor method to get at Mypackage's values, or export the variable to your namespace with [Exporter](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html).

Comment: Can you modify this to asnwer the question - "the package name is in a string"

Comment: rephrase of previous comment - this way looks fine if the other package is known in advance but I cant see how to use it if the package name is specified at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Beside the way that FM has already noted, you can access particular parts of a typeglob through it's hash-like interface:

```
my $array =  *{$ref}{ARRAY};
```

This can be handy to get to the parts, such as the `IO` portions, that don't have a sigil. I have a chapter about this sort of stuff in [Mastering Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527242).

Answer (score 0):

You need to dereference it: @$$ref instead of @$ref

Comment: Why the hate here? If you actually test my answer you will see it works.